# generate 100 milions record with monetdb

Tags: bigdata, monetdb, generated

my assignment is make a database with 100 millions record in mongetdb.for now my solution is generate a big file db.sql then import . size of that file is bigger than 6gb. I have imported near to 2 days.and i don't know when it finish. Somebody help me ,please!
thanks you .

Comment: monetdb and mongodb are different databases..please edit your question :)

Comment: lol, mongetdb. I would suggest importing by either switching off autocommit or using the copy into method.

Comment: thank you. it work. i just need ten minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest importing by either switching off autocommit (`START TRANSACTION; ... COMMIT;` or using the `COPY INTO` [method](https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/Manuals/SQLreference/CopyInto).

Comment: it's worked! i just take 10 minutes. I have tried normal method ,it take so long time, no less than 3 day LOL